# From Java parallelstream spawns other parallelStreams and fails seldom

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

Considering the following function:

```
public void execute4() {
        File filePath = new File(filePathData);
        File[] files = filePath.listFiles((File filePathData) -> filePathData.getName().endsWith("CDR"));
        List<CDR> cdrs = new ArrayList<CDR>();
        Arrays.asList(files).parallelStream().forEach(file -> readCDRP(cdrs, file));
        cdrs.sort(cdrsorter);
    }
```

which reads a list of Files containing CDR and executes the readCDRP() which is this:

```
private void readCDRP(List<CDR> cdrs, File file) {
    final CDR cdr = new CDR(file.getName());
    try (BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        List<String> lines = bfr.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());
        lines.parallelStream().forEach(e -> {
            String[] data = e.split(",", -1);
            CDREntry entry = new CDREntry(file.getName());
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                entry.setField(i, data[i]);
            }
            cdr.addEntry(entry);
        });

        if (cdr != null) {
            cdrs.add(cdr);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I observe is that occasionally and NOT all the time, I either get a ArrayIndexNotBound Exception at the readCDRP function over the line (*which is awkward, as the list of cdr is an ArrayList()* ):

```
cdr.addEntry(entry);
```

or
at the last line in execute4() where I apply the sorting.

I think the issue is that the first parallelStream from execute4 is not in a separate space in memory from the second parallelStream execution inside readCDRP() and also seems to share wrongly the data. Using "seem" word as I can't confirm and is just a hutch.

The questions are:
is my code buggy to the bone from JDK8 perspective? 
Is there a workaround using the same flow, something like using CountDownLatch for example?
Is limitation of the ForkJoinPool ?

Thanks for any responce....

**EDIT(1):**
The addEntry is part of a class itself:

```
class CDR {
        public final String fileName;
        private final List<CDREntry> entries = new ArrayList<CDREntry>();

        public CDR(String fileName) {
            super();
            this.fileName = fileName;
        }

        public List<CDREntry> getEntries() {
            return entries;
        }

        public List<CDREntry> addEntry(CDREntry e) {
            entries.add(e);
            return entries;
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return this.fileName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us `CDR.addEntry` method.

Comment: `cdr` is not thread safe so you can't alter in multiple threads safely.  I suggest you use a functional approach as `Kristoffer E` suggests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you starting programming in functional style you should prefer immutable objects which can be fully created via construction (or probably using builder pattern or some factory method). So your `CDREntry` class may look like this:

```
class CDREntry {
    private final String[] fields;
    private final String name;

    public CDREntry(String name, String[] fields) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fields = fields;
    }
    // Add getters and whatever
}
```

And your `CDR` class may look like this:

```
class CDR {
    private final String fileName;
    private final List<CDREntry> entries;

    public CDR(String fileName, List<CDREntry> entries) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    public List<CDREntry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return this.fileName;
    }
}
```

Having such classes things become easier. The rest of the code can be rewritten like this:

```
public void execute4() {
    File filePath = new File(filePathData);
    File[] files = filePath.listFiles((File data, String name) -> 
             data.getName().endsWith("CDR")); // fixed this line: it had compilation error
    List<CDR> cdrs = Arrays.stream(files).parallel()
            .map(this::readCDRP).sorted(cdrsorter)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private CDR readCDRP(File file) {
    try (BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        // I'm not sure that collecting lines into list 
        // before main processing was actually necessary
        return bfr.lines().parallelStream()
                .map(e -> new CDREntry(file.getName(), e.split(",", -1)))
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.toList(), list -> new CDR(file.getName(), list)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

In general remember that `forEach` is usually not the cleanest way to solve the tasks. It may be helpful when you integrate the streams into legacy code, but in general should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the whole rewrite. Gives a direct glimpse on the styling but certainly I am missing sections from the Stream java doc.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is broken from a thread safety point of view. In `readCDR` you add elements to the `cdrs` list which is an `ArrayList` that does not support concurrent writes. That is why it breaks.

A better approach would be to have `readCDR` return a `cdr` object and do something like:

```
 List<CDR> cdrs = Arrays.stream(files)
                        .parallel()
                        .map(this::readCDR)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also, using parallel streams for IO related operations is generally a bad idea, but that is another discussion.

Comment: So the API with lambdas is vulnerable to a code style as above. I had the impression that lists and collections are handled in better way. I mean that parallelStream and functional API handles them as if they were thread-safe.

Comment: @hephestos
Have a look at the JDK 8 API  for Streams https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

under "Stateless behaviors" it says 


"Stream pipeline results may be nondeterministic or incorrect if the behavioral parameters to the stream operations are stateful. .....  An example of a stateful lambda is the parameter to map() in:

    Set<Integer> seen = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
     stream.parallel().map(e -> { if (seen.add(e)) return 0; else return e; })
"

this is exactly what you where doing

Comment: @hephestos Yes, your style above is "broken". By modifying your externally defined collection you effectively bypass all the nice logic for properly handling collections in parallel. My example above is a thread safe way to create a list in parallel.

Comment: Ok I am learning, many thanks for the responces. Yes the API of Stream needs study.

Answer (score 2):

you are using a parallel stream and a lambda that has side effects 
(the lambda updates the ArrayList 'cdrs') 
try to use a Collector or a Reduction-Operation.